# What value does a new tag on a heavily downvoted/closed question have and what to do about it?

Tags: discussion, tags

This recent question has made me wonder if maybe we should delete a tag if the only question/s it points to have been heavily down voted and/or closed: 
[How do I tell other gay people that they sound stupid calling themselves "queer"?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/8275/how-do-i-tell-other-gay-people-that-they-sound-stupid-calling-themselves-queer), resulting in this somewhat lacking page: https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/queer

As you can see, the question created a new tag "queer" and as such, there are no other questions with that tag other than one which has been heavily down voted and closed. And so I was wondering how much (if any) worth does a tag like this have? While it is a valid tag that may apply to past/future questions, there are currently none, and simply re-making the tag if ever such a question arises is not a big deal.

The question is somewhat new and there is another meta post about whether to delete/re-open it. 
[Can the question about using the word "queer" be reopened, after a quick edit?](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2289/can-the-question-about-using-the-word-queer-be-reopened-after-a-quick-edit)
So this particular case may get re-opened, but I would appreciate answers assuming that won't happen anytime soon.

Is there any reason we should keep the tag alive, and if not, how should we go about removing it?

Comment: Tags will be automatically deleted by the system after 24 hours if there are no questions with that tag ([MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19753/how-can-we-get-rid-of-misspelled-and-unused-or-zombie-tags)). Not sure if deleted questions count towards that, but the tag could be edited out.

Answer (score 6):

If anything [queer](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/queer) would be a subset of [lgbt+](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lgbt%2b) and I would suspect that it's a small enough subset that it doesn't really need a separate tag at the moment.

Most people who would identify as queer wouldn't have a problem with identifying as LGBT+ but as demonstrated by that question the opposite isn't always true.

Comment: Seems appropriate for this specific case thankyou, how about more generally? Such as if another tag is in a similar position but doesn't fit into a subset?

Comment: Do you think changing the it will worth changing lgbt+ tag to lgbtq+ ?

Comment: @Vylix It doesn't make much difference to me. LGBT+ is slightly more recognizable than some of the longer acronyms though.